# Kibana 30s timeout with wide date range

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat, elk

I have a big problem with timeouts in Kibana. I'm gathering logs from Nginx by Filebeat and Elasticsearch pipeline. All is working well. But when I'm trying to fire up Dashboard Nginx Overview created by Filebeat with eg last 5 days Kibana timeouts after 30s.

ELK stack is placed on 1 server (only 1 instance) with no replica.
Index is rolled every day (Index has 1 shard)

First some data:

### Server:

```
CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 v3 @ 3.50GHz
SSD: 4x SSD Raid10 Micron_5200_MTFD
RAM: 256GB
```

### Stack

```
Elasticsearch 7.1.1
Kibana 7.1.1
Filebeat 7.1.1
```

### elasticsearch.yml

```
indices.queries.cache.size: 40%
```

### jvm.options

```
-Xms20g
-Xmx20g
```

Rest of option is default.

## Question

Is there any way to increase the speed of elasticsearch with my current setup? I would like to be able to fetch data from more than 3 days.

Comment: You could try to reproduce query in dev tools console, and later try to have a play with search profiler.

Comment: I discovered that problem only exists on dashboard but not on visualization.